# Angular 2 FormBuilder Error During Instantiation

Tags: typescript, angular

(Code has been updated with fix)

I am trying to build a form and add validation to a controlgroup so that I can check to see if the combination of two controls exist in an array of objects. I have the following code, but when I try to run my page, it gives me an error.

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of ClientFormComponent!.
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I am unsure of why it is unable to access the length property of my array. The "getClients()" method of my service works perfectly fine elsewhere in my app.Any thoughts would be great.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'client-form',
    templateUrl: './Scripts/typescript/client-form.component.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ClientService]
})

export class ClientFormComponent
{
    clientForm: ControlGroup;
    npi: AbstractControl;
    name: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private _clientService: ClientService, _fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.clientForm = _fb.group({ 'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 'npi': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, npiNumValidator, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)])] }, { asyncValidator: this.npiNameDupValidator.bind(this) });
        this.name = this.clientForm.controls['name'];
        this.npi = this.clientForm.controls['npi'];
    }
    

    clientList: Client[];
    active = true;


    onSubmit(value: Client) {
        this._clientService.addDeleteClient(value, true)
            .subscribe(
            client => this.clientList.push(client));        
    }    

    npiNameDupValidator(group: ControlGroup) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let name = group.controls['name'];
            let npi = group.controls['npi'];
            var found = false;

            this._clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {                
                for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                    alert(clients[i].name + ':' + name.value);
                    alert(clients[i].npi + ':' + npi.value);

                    if (clients[i].name == name.value && clients[i].npi == npi.value) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found) {
                    alert('Found!');
                    resolve({ npiNameDupe: true });
                }
                else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            });            
        });
    }
}


function npiNumValidator(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (isNaN(control.value)) {
        return { npiNAN: true };
    }
}
```

My template HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(clientForm.value)" [ngFormModel]="clientForm">
        <div class="form-group" style="float: left;">
            <label for="clientid">Client Id:</label>
            <input placeholder="QDX"id="clientid" type="text" class="form-control"  [ngFormControl]="clientForm.controls['name']">
            <div *ngIf="name.hasError('required') && name.touched"
                 class="alert alert-danger">Client ID is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="name.hasError('npiNAN')"
                 class="alert alert-danger">NPI must be a number</div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <label for="npi">NPI:</label>
            <input placeholder="0123456789" maxlength="10" id="npi" type="text" class="form-control" [ngFormControl]="clientForm.controls['npi']">
            <div *ngIf="npi.hasError('required') && npi.touched"
                 class="alert alert-danger">NPI is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="npi.hasError('npiNAN') && npi.touched"
                 class="alert alert-danger">NPI must be a number</div>
            <div *ngIf="npi.hasError('minlength') && npi.touched"
                 class="alert alert-danger">NPI must be 10 characters</div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div style="float: left; margin: 25px 0 0 10px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!clientForm.valid">Add</button>
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;" />
        <div *ngIf="clientForm.hasError('npiNameDupe')"
             class="alert alert-danger">NPI &amp; Name Combo Already Exist</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you try to implement an asynchronous validator. You should use the `asyncValidator` attribute instead on the `validator` one:

```
_fb.group({
  'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  'npi': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, (...)])]
}, { asyncValidator: this.npiNameDupValidator.bind(this) });
```

I would refactor your validator this way:

```
npiNameDupValidator(group: ControlGroup) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let name = group.controls['name'];
    let npi = group.controls['npi'];

    this._clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
      var clis = clients;
      var length = clis.length;
      var found = (...); // your processing here

      if (found) {
        resolve({ npiNameDupe: true });
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I refactored and this is great. Do you know how to display an error message on my page if the controlgroup has the "npiNameDupe" error? I updated my code above with the refactor as well as my template which includes what I thought would work for the npiNameDupe error.

Comment: You're welcome! Look fine for me. Perhaps a small comment: you could leverage the `pending` property since you use an asynchronous validator. See this article for more details: http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Comment: My error message isn't appearing for some reason. I can't figure out why. It disables the button perfectly fine, but the error message doesnt show up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Since `getClients()` is an observable, you'd need to set the length inside of the subscribe callback.

```
var clis: Client[];
var length = 0;
this._clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
    clis = clients;
    length = clis.length;
});
```

This ensures that length is properly set once data is returned to your subscribe.

As for WHY you are getting the error in the first place, you have not initialized your array.  You'd need to actually provide a default value since currently it is undefined which throws an error when you try to check length.

```
var clis: Client[] = [];
```